# Django: Form object has no attribute cleaned_data - save() method

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Ok so I actually solved this one by accident and would simply like to understand what happened.

I have my own user registration form BaseCreationForm which extends a ModelForm and uses a UserProfile as its model. All the validation methods were working fine, but the save method was giving me grief. Whenever I tried to create a user (the profile is created in the view, I may refactor this), Django would tell me that "BaseCreationForm object has no attribute cleaned data".

BUT, when out of frustration and running out of ideas I added a simple "print self" statement before creating the user in the save() method, the problem disappeared and users are being created normally. Below are a couple of clean() methods that work, the save() method and a snippet from the view that calls the clean() and save() method.

clean() methods working normally

```
#example clean methods, both work beautifully
def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
    if not email:
        raise forms.ValidationError(self.error_messages['no_email'])

    try:
        User.objects.get(email=email)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return email
    raise forms.ValidationError(self.error_messages['duplicate_email'])

def clean_password2(self):
    # Check that the two password entries match
    password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
    password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
    if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            self.error_messages['password_mismatch'])
    return password2
```

save() method:

```
 #save method requiring wizardry
 def save(self, commit=True):
    #This line makes it work. When commented, the error appears
    print self
    ###  
    user = User.objects.create_user(
        username=self.cleaned_data.get("username"),
        first_name=self.cleaned_data["first_name"],
        last_name=self.cleaned_data["last_name"],
        email=self.cleaned_data["email"],
        )
    user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user
```

And the view (some stuff left out):

```
class RegistrationView(FormView):
    template_name = 'register.html'
    form_class = BaseCreationForm
    model = UserProfile
    success_url = '/account/login/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form                    = BaseCreationForm(self.request.POST,
                                                  self.request.FILES)
        user                    = form.save()
        profile                 = user.get_profile()
        profile.user_type       = form.cleaned_data['user_type']
        profile.title           = form.cleaned_data['title']
        profile.company_name    = form.cleaned_data['company_name']
        .
        .
        .
        profile.save()
        return super(RegistrationView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't be re-instantiating the form inside the `form_valid` method. That's called when the form is already valid, and indeed the form is passed into the method. You should use that instead.

(Note that the actual error is because you haven't called `form.is_valid()` at all, but as I say above you shouldn't, because the view is already doing it.)

Comment: Oh I see, thanks. The reason it was there is that I was uploading a file and had trouble doing that earlier and some sources said I should make sure that it includes (self.request.FILES). But the error must've been elsewhere because because now that I just commented it out it still works.